# Ruby on Rails has_many through association objects before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

on a Ruby on Rails project I'm trying to access association objects on an ActiveRecord prior to saving everything to the database.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :purchase_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :purchase_items

  validate :item_validation

  def item_ids=(ids)
    ids.each do |item_id|
      purchase_items.build(item_id: item_id)
    end
  end

  private

  def item_validation
    items.each do |item|
      ## Lookup something with the item
      if item.check_something
        errors.add :base, "Error message"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

If I build out my object like so:
`purchase = Purchase.new(item_ids: [1, 2, 3])` and try to save it the `item_validation` method doesn't have the items collection populated yet, so even though items have been set set it doesn't get a chance to call the `check_something` method on any of them.

Is it possible to access the items collection before my purchase model and association models are persisted so that I can run validations against them?

If I change my `item_validation` method to be:

```
def item_validation
  purchase_items.each do |purchase_item|
    item = purchase_item.item
    ## Lookup something with the item
    if item.something
       errors.add :base, "Error message"
    end
  end
end
```

it seems to work the way I want it to, however I find it hard to believe that there is no way to directly access the items collection with rails prior to my purchase and associated records being saved to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try to adding the argument inverse_of: in the has_many and belongs_to definitions. The inverse_of argument it's the name of the relation on the other model, For example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, inverse_of: :post
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :comments
end
```

Don't forget to add it also on the other classes, such as PurchaseItem and Item

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Remove your own `item_ids=` method - rails generates one for you (see [collection_singular_ids=ids](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)). This might already solve your problem.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :purchase_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :purchase_items

  validate :item_validation

  private

  def item_validation
    items.each do |item|
      ## Lookup something with the item
      if item.check_something
        errors.add :base, "Error message"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The second thing that comes in my mind looking at your code: Move the validation to the `Item` class. So:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchase_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :purchase_items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchase_items
  has_many :purchases, through: :purchase_items

  validate :item_validation

  private

  def item_validation
      if check_something
        errors.add :base, "Error message"
      end
  end
end
```

Your `Purchase` record will also be invalid if one of the `Item`s is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have documentation that indicates `purchase = Purchase.new(item_ids: [1, 2, 3])` does what you're expecting?

To me that looks like you are just setting the non-database attribute 'item_ids' to an array (i.e. not creating an association).

Your Purchase model should not even have any foreign key columns to set directly. Instead there are entries in the `purchase_items` table that have a `purchase_id` and `item_id`. To create a link between your purchase and the three items you need to create three entries in the joiner table.

What happens if you just do this instead?:

```
purchase = Purchase.new
purchase.items = Item.find([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.associations = [association_objects]` and an `Association Callback` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't access them because `id` of `Purchase` isn't available before record saved. But as you mention you have access to first level association `purchase_items`, so you can extract all ids and pass them in `where` for `Item`:

```
items = Item.where(purchase_item_id: purchase_items.map(&:id))
```