# Rails: Check while building/before saving an object if association matching certain condition is there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called Timesheet which has many TimesheetRows. TimesheetRow belongs to a job.

```
class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timesheet_rows, inverse_of: timesheet
end
class TimesheetRow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timesheet, inverse_of: timesheet_rows
  belongs_to :job
end
```

While building a timesheet object from logs, I am trying to check if timesheet_row corresponding to a job has been already built or not, as follows.

```
timesheet = Timesheet.new()

if timesheet.timesheet_rows.exists?(job_id:n)
  #Do something
else 
  timesheet.timesheet_rows.build(job_id:n)
end
```

I have tried .exists?(condition) , .find(:all, condition) , .find_by_job_id(n) , .where(condition) etc. All query from database, and thus won't be useful here.

I have browsed for hours now, looking for some magic method but couldn't find any. Really, will I just have to loop through all the associations?

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728484/ruby-on-rails-has-many-through-association-objects-before-save).

Thanks

Comment: Why not set an `uniqueness validation` on `job_id` in `TimesheetRow` model? It works in your case.

Comment: That validation check will happen whiling saving the timesheet right? I just want to build the timesheet not save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ruby's [`select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-select) method, and then checking if the resulting array is empty.

```
if timesheet.timesheet_rows.select { |tr| tr.job_id == n }.empty?
  timesheet.timesheet_rows.build(job_id: n)
else 
  # Do something
end
```

As @Bot suggested in the comments, you can also use the `any?` rather than `select` and `empty?`.

```
if timesheet.timesheet_rows.any? { |tr| tr.job_id == n }
  # Do something
else 
  timesheet.timesheet_rows.build(job_id: n)
end
```

Comment: Thanks JKen. Now I see three options .any?{}, .detect{}.empty?, .select{}.empty? .
I like .any?{} though. Can you add that to your answer?

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help. And great call with `any?`, I added it to my answer.